# Is it cURL? Is it a POST? "Pasting" into a website from a bash script

Tags: bash, web, curl, post

I'm working on a bash script that would get the product name from it's product code (SKU) from retailer's website.

So, I'm working for this retailer and it has its website (it's like Amazon or eBay). When you go there and put the SKU code (that you know) into a search bar, there will be no query results, it will take you directly to that product. Let's say the SKU is 654321 and let's say it's an iMac (whatever). I hope you get the idea.

What I'm trying to do is to write a bash script, that when you deliver that SKU code, it will "paste" it into that search bar on a website and after greping or AWKing the results, it will give you the name of that product (let's say that iMac M1, 256GB and so on and whatever it is).

IMPORTANT: This SKU code I mentioned does not appear in the website's URL.

I thought I could use cURL or something, but because I don't have experience with it, I got lost when doing research.

Sorry for not mentioning the acctual website, but I acctually work for them and at some point I would have probably said something I can't or at least something I shouldn't have and it's only a fun project for me.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not clear. Are you trying to display the complete product name once the product details page is loaded after a user submits a sku code on your website? Or you're trying to get the product name from a different website than yours?

Comment: Does it have some public API you can query instead of trying to directly scrape a html page?

Comment: Thanks for replying.
To answer both of your questions: 
To you @Shawn - that was my first thought, but there is no API available unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for replying.
@Brac: You go to that website and it has a search bar (exactly the same idea as if you went to eBay and search for a Dell laptopl). If you already know the code of the product and you put it into that search bar, it will take you directly to it (its own URL). So I want my script to "go" to that website, "put" that code of the product in the search bar and then send me the full url of that products address, so I can wget to my computer and then using tools like grep or awk simply extract the name of that product  knowing that this name is attached to that product.

Comment: #Google I don't know if it's any helpful to anyone reading this, but it seems like that if you simply put the name of the retailer I've mentioned above and the code of a desired product, it seems like the first link Google shows you is the direct page of that product. So like I said, if I could then download that specific site, I could grep or awk through it to find the name of that product attached to that code.

Comment: You can achieve this with both methods (curl -X POST), but it depends alot on how it's built on the other side, and I doubt you should be doing this without letting them know what you are trying to do. I have created a few scripts in order to ban bots from reaching my websites, your script would most probably fail to reach my sites. Popular portals are usually doing the same. Unless you'll generate very low trafic on their website, I suggest you contact them and ask them how their form is built in order to identify the method to use.

Comment: It would be mild, like maybe 20 or 30 times a day in the working hours.  You said I could achive this using curl -X POST. Could you show me the example?